# how to make zend webroot transparently absolute or relative?

Tags: zend-framework, path, relative-path, absolute-path, document-root

I'm developing a Zend web application with classic file hierarchy structure, ie:

```
application/
docs/
library/
public/
tests/
```

Since the app is used in different machine with different server configurations, In the view scripts I would like to have link paths that work independently from where the document root has been set in the web server configuration.

Examples follow:

Host FOO is configured to point the document root to $APP/public/, and so the browser url would be "http://myapp/"

Host BAR is not configured like FOO and the browser url is "http://localhost/my/deep/path/to/$APP/public"

In the view script I would like to write the following:

```
<img src="<?= $urlbase ?>images/logo.gif" />
```

to display an images which is in $APP/public/images/logo.gif, in such a way that it works both in FOO and in BAR hosts.

What do I use in place of $urlbase?

PS: I tried to use:

```
<?= $this->url() ?>
```

but it doesn't take into account the controllers, actions, and get parameters contained in the url, that is at "http://myapp/index/login/" it returns "/index/login/", while I need it to return just "/".

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BaseUrl helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl)

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/logo.gif') ?>" />
```